# Problem related to direct sum of specific eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Please provide a **hint** or **related but easier problem** (not the solution).

**Problem:** Suppose $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ and $T$ is a linear operator on V such that  $\prod_{i=1}^{m}(T-\lambda _i I) = $0 for some **distinct** $\lambda i \in F$. Prove that V is the direct sum of
the $\lambda_i$-eigenspaces of $T$. 
[Note: $V$ may **not** be assumed finite-dimensional.]

The fact that $V$ may not be finite-dimensional takes away some of my standard tools for this kind of problem, like induction, and thinking in terms of a diagram that maps basis vectors to basis vectors.  I think I probably need some more abstract tools.

So far I have figured out that, if $v_i$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, then $v_i$ is also an eigenvector of all transformations of the form $(T-\lambda_k)$ with $k \neq i$, so I can easily see that the converse of the statement is true.

Thank you for any help you can offer.  I am trying to learn math on my own in a place with few people who can help me, and I have been stuck on this problem for a quite a while.

Comment: Consider some arbitrary $v \in V$. Can you show that it is an eigenvector of $T$?

Comment: But, in general, not all $v \in V$ are eigenvectors of T, and therefore that's not what I am asked to prove. The question asks to show instead that all $v \in V$ can be expressed as a unique linear combination of eigenvectors of $T$

 For example, let $V= \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $T(x,y,z)= (x,2y,3z) $. Then the set of eigenvectors of $T$ consists of all vectors represented by points on any of the x, y, or z axes, **not** all $v \in V$.  However, it is easy to see that all $v \in V$ **are** unique linear combinations of eigenvectors of $T$

Comment: This is completely true.